# QEMU/KVM network interface address

Tags: networking, ip, qemu, kvm, nic

What's the use of the `addr` value when specifying a new network interface on QEMU/KVM ?

Example: `qemu -hda deb.img -net nic,addr=192.168.1.10`

Is there a way to specify directly the IP address of a network interface ?

(Directly means at the moment when we launch the guest)

Answer (score 4):

If you call

```
# /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
    -vnc :0 \
    -machine pc,accel=kvm,usb=off \
    -m 2048 \
    -net nic,addr=192.16.0.1
```

You receive errror:
qemu-system-x86_64: Invalid PCI device address 192.16.0.1 for device e1000

Addr param is not an ip address, it's a device id.

If you call

```
# /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -drive file=/opt/test.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
    -vnc :0 \
    -machine pc,accel=kvm,usb=off \
    -m 2048 \
    -net nic,addr=0x10
```

nic was added as device 00:10.0 (Domain 0, Bus 0, Device 0x10, Function 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the static IP address in the guest OS.
I think IP is not a physical feature for the guest, but you can set the MAC or BDF of the NIC with the param